# Python Find and Replace texts in all sub directories

Tags: python, automation

I'm trying to find and replace texts in all sub directorys of the given directory and here is my code.

```
import os

folderLocation = "C:\\Users\\josh\\Desktop\\target\\xml\\"
divider = "\\"

pseudoDictionaryKey = []
pseudoDictionaryValue = []


with open("C:/Users/josh/Desktop/FILENAMES.txt", "r") as fi:
    for line in fi:
        tokens = line.strip().split("-->")
        pseudoDictionaryKey.append(tokens[0])
        pseudoDictionaryValue.append(tokens[1])

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folderLocation):
    for fileIn in files:
        if fileIn in pseudoDictionaryKey:
            os.rename(folderLocation + subdir, folderLocation + pseudoDictionaryValue[pseudoDictionaryKey.index(fileIn)])

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(folderLocation):
    for fileIn in files:
        result = ""
        with open(folderLocation + fileIn,"r") as fi:            
            result = fi.read()
            for i, value in enumerate(pseudoDictionaryKey):
                result = result.replace(pseudoDictionaryKey[i],pseudoDictionaryValue[i])
        with open(folderLocation + fileIn,"w") as fo:
            fo.write(result)
```

It finds and replaces the texts but it does not knows how to enter subdirs I want it to rename the texts in every files inside the directory and sub directorys like Open every file inside the directory not just the ones defined in FILENAMES.txt

Comment: after scan your directory with `os.walk`, you can create a list of file, use `os.path.ifile(file_path`), e.g: `files = [file for file in files if os.path.isfile(file)]`, then iterate over that list to process your files

Comment: What do you mean? I want it to open all the files inside the directory xml.